# How to clear terminal using short cut key in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser

This is GDS command to run on Travelport terminal through API. Every command provide a response and after type clear terminal would be cleaned but same I need using shortcut(ctr+any key)

```
 Command.GDS = {    
  getFsCallback: function(input, output, response_result) {
  setTimeout( function() {
    window.scrollTo( {
        top: 300000,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    }, 1000 );
    var gds_provider = $('#gds_provider').val();
    var gds_output = build_api_call(gds_provider, input.join(" "));
    $('#overlay').fadeOut();
    if (input == 'clear') {
        return output.clear();
    }    
    if(gds_output == 'Enter Password <br><br>'){
      $("#cmdline").attr("type","Password");
    }else{
      $("#cmdline").attr("type","text");
    }     this.clear = function() {
       outputElement.innerHTML = '';
       return this;
     };
 };

    return output.write(gds_output);
    return function() { 
      // Add Dir
      Terminal.Filesystem.pwd.getDirectory(input[1], {create: true}, function() {}, Terminal.FilesystemErrorHandler);
    };
  }
};
```

This is my js code

```
     this.clear = function() {
       outputElement.innerHTML = '';
       return this;
     };
 };
```

Please any help would be appreciated

I would like to clean terminal using any shortcut key like using(ctr+Q) or any of (ctr+key)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a key event listener to the document and detect the combination of the "Ctrl" key and the desired key. If the combination is pressed, you can call the clear function to clear the terminal output

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.code === "KeyQ") {
    outputElement.innerHTML = '';
  }
});
```

replace "KeyQ" with the desired key code that you want to use as the shortcut